# Unable to scrape 2nd table from Fbref.com

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the 2nd table in the page seen below from the link - https://fbref.com/en/comps/82/stats/Indian-Super-League-Stats#all_stats_standard
on google collab.

but pd.read_html("https://fbref.com/en/comps/82/stats/Indian-Super-League-Stats#all_stats_standard") only gives me the first table.

Please help me understand where I am going wrong.

[Snippet of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOO3f.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to read that data:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url= 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/82/stats/Indian-Super-League-Stats#all_stats_standard'
response = requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '')
df = pd.read_html(response, header=1)[2]
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    Rk  Player  Nation  Pos Squad   Age Born    MP  Starts  Min 90s Gls Ast G-PK    PK  PKatt   CrdY    CrdR    Gls.1   Ast.1   G+A G-PK.1  G+A-PK  Matches
0   1   Sahal Abdul Samad   in IND  MF  Kerala Blasters 24  1997    20  19  1443    16.0    5   1   5   0   0   0   0   0.31    0.06    0.37    0.31    0.37    Matches
1   2   Ayush Adhikari  in IND  MF  Kerala Blasters 21  2000    14  6   540 6.0 0   0   0   0   0   3   1   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    Matches
2   3   Gani Ahammed Nigam  in IND  FW  NorthEast Utd   23  1998    6   0   66  0.7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    Matches
3   4   Airam   es ESP  FW  Goa 33  1987    13  8   751 8.3 6   1   5   1   2   0   0   0.72    0.12    0.84    0.60    0.72    Matches
4   5   Alex    br BRA  MF  Jamshedpur  32  1988    20  12  1118    12.4    1   4   1   0   0   2   0   0.08    0.32    0.40    0.08    0.40    Matches
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
302 292 João Victor br BRA  MF  Hyderabad FC    32  1988    18  18  1590    17.7    5   1   3   2   2   3   0   0.28    0.06    0.34    0.17    0.23    Matches
303 293 David Williams  au AUS  FW  Mohun Bagan 33  1988    15  6   602 6.7 4   1   4   0   1   2   0   0.60    0.15    0.75    0.60    0.75    Matches
304 294 Banana Yaya cm CMR  DF  Bengaluru   30  1991    5   2   229 2.5 0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0.00    0.39    0.39    0.00    0.39    Matches
305 295 Joe Zoherliana  in IND  DF  NorthEast Utd   22  1999    9   6   677 7.5 0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.13    0.13    0.00    0.13    Matches
306 296 Mark Zothanpuia in IND  MF  Hyderabad FC    19  2002    3   0   63  0.7 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    Matches
307 rows × 24 columns
```

Relevant pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html